# HttpClient not available Shared Library project Xamarin

Tags: rest, xamarin, httpclient

I come to you for a common problem, but unfortunately, I was unable to find a solution.

I make a xamarin.form application, it is not a PCL, but a Shared Library project. I would like to use a REST api, and for this, I need to use a HttpClient instance. 
Well, here is the problem. With a PCL, I just have to add the nuget package Microsoft HTTP Client Libraries, and then I can use the HttpClient class.

With a Shared Library project, I cannot add this nuget package to the main project (which I think is normal). So I it add to to the .Droid one, and the .iOS one (oh, by the way, I am using a mac, and Xamarin Studio, if it can help).
When I add the Nuget package, I can add this line : using System.Net.Http; but the class HttpClient is still unavailable. What I mean by unavailable is, I just cannot use this class (The type or namespace httpclient could not be found, are you missing an assembly reference ? )

Is there a way to use HttpClient class in a Shared Project, and not a PCL ? If yes, how ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There must have been an error while installing the Microsoft HTTP Client Libraries to your Android and iOS projects, because these project types are not supported.

> Could not install package 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build 1.0.14'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

The `HttpClient` comes with the Xamarin base class library https://developer.xamarin.com/api/namespace/System.Net.Http/.

So you do not need the Microsoft HTTP Client Libraries and only have to

- reference your shared project in your Android/iOS project
- add the Library `System.Net.Http` to your Android/iOS project
- add `using System.Net.Http`.

On Xamarin Studio: Edit References > Packages > Check `System.Net.Http`

On Visual Studio: Add Reference > Assemblies > Framework > Check `System.Net.Http`

**Protip**: In addition, you could have a look at Paul Betts' ModernHttpClient: https://github.com/paulcbetts/ModernHttpClient and Kerry Lothrops blog post about HttpClientHandlers http://kerry.lothrop.de/httpclient-flavors/

Comment: Thank you so much ! That made the trick !! Thanks for the ModenHttpClient link as well.

Comment: If an answer solves your problem, mark it as answered, else it will remain in the unanswered question lane. Thanks.